# What the equivalent of OpenGL glStencilFunc in Metal?

Tags: objective-c, opengl, metal, metalkit, stencil-buffer

How to translate to Metal the following OpenGL instruction:

```objectivec
glStencilFunc(Func, Ref, Mask);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's try to extend Hamid's correct answer with some actual Swift code...

Assuming you already have the basic Metal setup done:

```swift
let metalView: MTKView = /* ... */
let commandBuffer: MTLCommandBuffer = /* ... */

let device: MTLDevice = metalView.device!
```

Let's create a `MTLTexture` to store the *stencil buffer*:

```swift
let stencilTexture: MTLTexture

// Set up a texture for rendering the *8 bit unsigned* stencil buffer.
let stencilTextureDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor()
stencilTextureDescriptor.textureType = .type2D
stencilTextureDescriptor.width = Int(metalView.frame.width)
stencilTextureDescriptor.height = Int(metalView.frame.height)
stencilTextureDescriptor.pixelFormat = .stencil8
stencilTextureDescriptor.storageMode = .private

// Set this option if you use the given texture 
// as a stencil render target in any render pass.
stencilTextureDescriptor.usage = [.renderTarget]

stencilTexture = device.makeTexture(descriptor: stencilTextureDescriptor)
```

Create the `MTLRenderPipelineState` as usual but be sure to set the stencil *attachment* too:

```swift
let rendePipelineState: MTLRenderPipelineState

let renderPipelineDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
/* ...standard render pipeline configuration (e.g., render states, etc)... */
renderPipelineDescriptor.stencilAttachmentPixelFormat = .stencil8 
rendePipelineState = try! device.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: renderPipelineDescriptor)
```

Next configure the `MTLRenderPassDescriptor` and create a `MTLRenderCommandEncoder`:

```swift
let renderEncoder: MTLRenderCommandEncoder 

let renderPassDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()

renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .clear
renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColorMake(0, 0, 0, 1)
renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = .store

// Configure these depending on your rendering pass stencil semantics.
renderPassDescriptor.stencilAttachment.texture = stencilTexture
renderPassDescriptor.stencilAttachment.clearStencil = 0
renderPassDescriptor.stencilAttachment.loadAction = .clear
renderPassDescriptor.stencilAttachment.storeAction = .store

renderEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPassDescriptor)!
renderEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(rendePipelineState)
```

Now create a `MTLDepthStencilState` with the desired stencil buffer configuration:

```swift
let depthAndStencilState: MTLDepthStencilState

let stencilDescriptor = MTLStencilDescriptor()
stencilDescriptor.depthStencilPassOperation = .incrementClamp

// ## glStencilFunc(FUNC, _, _) ##
stencilDescriptor.stencilCompareFunction = .equal 

// ## glStencilFunc(_, _, MASK) ##
stencilDescriptor.readMask = 0xFF_FF_FF_FF 

let depthAndStencilDescriptor = MTLDepthStencilDescriptor()
depthAndStencilDescriptor.depthCompareFunction = .always
depthAndStencilDescriptor.isDepthWriteEnabled = false
depthAndStencilDescriptor.frontFaceStencil = stencilDescriptor
depthAndStencilDescriptor.backFaceStencil = stencilDescriptor

depthAndStencilState = device.makeDepthStencilState(descriptor: depthAndStencilDescriptor)!
renderEncoder.setDepthStencilState(depthAndStencilState)

// ## glStencilFunc(_, REF, _) ##
renderEncoder.setStencilReferenceValue(1)
```

Finally, do the rendering as usual:

```swift
/* ...encode rendering primitives... */
renderEncoder.endEncoding()
```

Answer (score 4):

[MTLStencilDescriptor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlstencildescriptor?language=objc) an object that defines the front-facing or back-facing stencil operations of a depth and stencil state object.

> A stencil test is a comparison between a masked reference value and a
>   masked value stored in a stencil attachment. (A value is masked by
>   performing a logical AND operation on it with the readMask value.) The
>   MTLStencilDescriptor object defines how to update the contents of the
>   stencil attachment, based on the results of the stencil test and the
>   depth test.
>
> The stencilCompareFunction property defines the stencil test. The
>   stencilFailureOperation, depthFailureOperation, and
>   depthStencilPassOperation properties specify what to do to a stencil
>   value stored in the stencil attachment for three different test
>   outcomes: if the stencil test fails, if the stencil test passes and
>   the depth test fails, or if both stencil and depth tests succeed,
>   respectively. writeMask determines which stencil bits can be modified
>   as the result of a stencil operation.

---

> I see where to put the value of Func and Mask with
>   MTLStencilDescriptor, but where go the value of REF ?

[setStencilReferenceValue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlrendercommandencoder/1515697-setstencilreferencevalue?language=objc) sets a stencil reference value for both front and back stencil comparison tests.

Comment: thanks @0xBFE1A8, I see where to put the value of Func and Mask with MTLStencilDescriptor, but where go the value of REF ?